# Are there any Powershell modules specifically for IIS6 administration?

Tags: iis, iis-6, powershell

I'm looking to manage/administer many IIS6 servers remotely via Powershell (query sites, iis settings, etc).

Is this possible? Is there a Microsoft-supported module out there? Or do I have to use WMI-Object/WebAdministration?

If so, could some one give me some quick instructions on doing some simple "get info" commands in Powershell to a remote IIS6 machine?

(It's frustrating that there is a nice IIS7/Microsoft-supported module out there: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/428/getting-started-with-the-iis-70-powershell-snap-in/ But not an IIS6 one easily found.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scripting options have gotten better over time, and with IIS7 they got much better yet.  You're right it's sure nice for IIS7, but that puts IIS6 behind.

In IIS6, you can use WMI through Powershell, or else you can script using WMI or ADSI over WSH.

I would start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525309.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525309.aspx) and [here](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/en-us/site/search?f[0].Type=Tag&f[0].Value=IIS%206.0).